# Criar countdown timer no javascript

Tags: html

Olá, gostaria de criar um contador de tempo nesse formato: "Carrinho reservado por *10m 10s*"

Encontrei esse tutorial mas nele não tem nesse estilo https://albert-gonzalez.github.io/easytimer.js/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que fez até o momento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia,

Você precisa definir um intervalo de 1 segundo, de maneira que uma função seja chamada constantemente. Para isso, utilize o setInterval;

Tente algo assim:

```js
var tempoEmMinutos = 15;
var expiracao = new  Date(new Date().getTime() + tempoEmMinutos * 60000);

contador = window.setInterval(function(){
    faltam = expiracao - new Date();
    if (faltam <= 0){
        window.clearInerval(contador);
        console.log("Prazo expirado");
    }
    minutos = Math.floor(faltam / 60000);
    segundos = faltam % 60000;
    tempoRestante = `${minutos}:${segundos.toString().substring(0,2)}`;

    //abaixo, coloque no lugar de 'tempo' o id do elemento do html que contem o timer
    document.getElementById('tempo').innerText = tempoRestante;
    console.log(tempoRestante);
}, 1000);
```

[Exemplo em funcionamento](https://jsfiddle.net/dm38fsoq/)